# unable to replace a part of json value using fs javascript

Tags: javascript, json

this is my js code

```
let content019 = JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync("./settings.json"));
// edit or add property
content019.api.client.locations[1] = 999999999999;
//write file
fs.writeFileSync('settings.json', JSON.stringify(content019,null ,2));
```

i tried using content019.api.client.locations[1] but it changed the inner part to `"1": "999....`

this is a part of my json file

```
        "1": {
          "name": "Germany",
          "type": null
        },
        "2": {
          "name": "Singapore",
          "type": null
        }
      },
```

i want it to only change `"1": {` to `"999999999999": {`

even tried content019.api.client.locations.1, didnt work. received error unexpected number

Comment: Json you posted is invalid. pls post valid json

Answer (score 1):

you have to use a string, not a number index. Since your json is invalid, I can only assume that the first part is ok, so you can try

```
content019.api.client.locations["1"] = 999999999999;
```

or maybe

```
content019.api.client.locations["999999"] = content019.api.client.locations["1"];
delete content019.api.client.locations["1"];
```